# How do I populate a column with the results of a SQL statement dynamically created in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamically created SQL count(*) statement in column 3 where the table name is the dynamic element. I want to put the results of the SQL in column 3 into column 4. How can this be done?

```
;with cteTables
as(
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
            ,statmnt = 'select count(*) cnt from '+t.name+' where sq = 0'
            ,Totals = 0
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'SQ'
), cteTots
as
(
select ColumnName,  TableName,  statmnt
       ,Totals2 = '' --<---------------------  
from cteTables
)
select * from cteTots
```

Comment: Your question would be easier to digest (IMHO) if you instead showed the complete query you want to run, along with sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000);

SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT '+ t.name + ' AS TableName, '+ c.name +' AS ColumnName, 
               (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+ t.name +' WHERE '+ c.name +' = 0) As Total
               FROM '+ t.name 
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'SQ'

EXEC(@SQL)
```